Parallel transport of a hermitian form on the fiber $E_x$
I have the following problem: Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a complex vector bundle over a complex manifold $M$, and let $v_x$ a hermitian form defined on the fiber $E_x$ such that it is invariant under the holonomy group $\mathrm{Hol}_x(D)$ of a connection $D$ defined on $E$.
Using parallel transport, we can extend $v_x$ to a unique hermitian form $v$ on E such that v is compatible with the connection $D$.
Regarding a hermitian form on $E$ as a section of $E^*\otimes \bar{E}^*$, and using the induced connection (also denoted as $D$), we can take the parallel transport $P_\gamma v_x$ along a curve $\gamma$. The resulting section defined along $\gamma$ is, by construction, a hermitian form compatible with the connection $D$, i.e., $Dv=0$.
Now, I'm having troubles proving the uniqueness of the form $v$. The fact that $v_x$ is invariant under the holonomy group should imply directly that $v$ is independent from the choose of the curve $\gamma$. Since if we have to curves $\gamma$ and $\lambda$  from $x$ to $y$, then $\lambda^{-1}\gamma$ is a loop based in $x$.
My first idea was trying to use the fact that $P_\gamma$ preserves the form $v$ since its compatible with $D$. Another idea was trying to proof that
$$ P_\gamma v_x=v_x(P_\gamma\cdot,P_\gamma\cdot)?$$
Where the left hand $P_\gamma$ is the parallel transport of the induced connection, and the right hand $P_\gamma$ is the parallel transport of the original connection.
Is this the right way to prove it, or it is a simpler idea that I'm missing?

Let $v^{\prime}$ be another such hermitian form. Then $D(v-v^{\prime}) =0$ and $v^{\prime}_x=v_x.$ Is that helpful?
